# Charset encoding of $.ajax json data

Tags: ajax, json, encoding

I make simple ajax request.
code is like this.

```
var paramObject = new Object();
    paramObject.cd_nm01 = 'farm';
    paramObject.cd_nm02 = 'server';
    paramObject.cd_nm03 = 'cpu_num';
    paramObject.cd_nm04 = 'mem_size';
    paramObject.cd_nm05 = 'user_hdd';
    paramObject.cd_nm06 = 'net_sprt';
    paramObject.cd_nm07 = 'net_type';

    var codes = JSON.stringify(paramObject);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        cache: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;      charset=UTF-8');
        },
        url: '/common/getCodes',
        data: {
        'jParam' : codes
        },
        success: function(data, status ,xhr) {
        console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(xhr){
        }
    });
```

I want send data of this: `"'cd_nm':'farm','cd_nm':'server','cd_nm':'cpu_num','cd_nm':'mem_size','cd_nm':'user_hdd','cd_nm':'net_sprt','cd_nm':'net_type'}"`

but in controller(Spring 3.1),
if I get those values from request,
they looks like below.

```
%7B%22cd_nm01%22%3A%22farm%22%2C%22cd_nm02%22%3A%22server%22%2C%22cd_nm03%22%3A%22cpu_num%22%2C%22cd_nm04%22%3A%22mem_size%22%2C%22cd_nm05%22%3A%22user_hdd%22%2C%22cd_nm06%22%3A%22net_sprt%22%2C%22cd_nm07%22%3A%22net_type%22%7D
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your request is just url encoded, like it should be.  If you decode it it looks like this:

{"cd_nm01":"farm","cd_nm02":"server","cd_nm03":"cpu_num","cd_nm04":"mem_size","cd_nm05":"user_hdd","cd_nm06":"net_sprt","cd_nm07":"net_type"}

That looks like valid json to me.  The form that you want to send the data in doesn't look right.  You want to use single quotes and you don't have a leading bracket.  If you don't want the 01, 02, 03 suffixes you probably need to change the JSON.stringify method to accept an array of strings instead of an object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try to resolve those problems by using your advise.